# How to deal with unique field generated by hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, many-to-many

Getting right to the point, I'm trying to build the following logic to *hibernate* relationships.

> A Resource has many read groups.
>
> A Resource has many write groups.
>
> Both groups are Groups class.

What I did until now:

**ResourcePage.class**

```
public class ResourcePage {
  /*
  useless code
  */
  private Set read;
  private Set write;
  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
    fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
    targetEntity = Groups.class)
  @JoinTable(name = "resourcepage_read_permissions")
  public Set getRead() {
    return read;
  }

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
    fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
    targetEntity = Groups.class)
  @JoinTable(name = "resourcepage_write_permissions")
  public Set getWrite() {
    return write;
  }
  /*
  useless code
  */    
}
```

The tables is created as expected.

[image]

However, hibernate is generating an *unique constraint* to **id of group** and this is giving me a big problem because sometimes two different resources can be same group as read group.

[image]

How do you guys deal with it?
How can I make *hibernate* not generate this unique constraint?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Guys, this was a mistake I commited, using `@manytomany` relationship instead `@onetomany` may solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `@ManyToMany` instead of `@OneToMany`.

Comment: I've already noticed that, but you were fast identifying the problem. Thanks a lot.